# How to transfer fund to route linked account in Razor pay through orders

Tags: javascript, node.js, razorpay

In Razorpay I have created an order with some amount, and also completed the payment transaction for the order, but now I need to transfer the amount to the linked account using the route, but the issue is when I use their `transfer with order` API from postman(which they provided in the docs). It's giving an error. What do I need to do in order to link it to the transfer and then complete the payment?

> {
> "error": {
> "code": "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
> "description": "The amount field is required.",
> "source": "business",
> "step": "payment_initiation",
> "reason": "input_validation_failed",
> "metadata": {},
> "field": "amount"
> }
> }

But I have provided the amount field in the body of the request, here is what the body looks like

```
{
    "amount": 10000, // this is the smallest unit(also tried with the larger unit)
    "currency":"INR",
    "transfers": [
        {
            "account": "acc_hhsk",
            "amount": 10000,
            "currency": "INR",
            "notes": {
                "branch": "Chess Program",
                "name": "Nilesh Kumar"
            },
            "linked_account_notes": [
                "branch"
            ],
            "on_hold": false,
            "on_hold_until": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Before this, I have successfully generated the order_id. Please help me find how to link order_id with the transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Pass like below it will work.

```
use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$transfer['transfers'][0]['account'] = "acc_IGd0hn6ZZ6khPr";
$transfer['transfers'][0]['amount'] = "800000";
$transfer['transfers'][0]['currency'] = "INR";
$notes['name'] = "sshhss";
$notes['roll_no'] = "IEC2011025";
$transfer['transfers'][0]['notes'] = $notes;
$transfer['transfers'][0]['linked_account_notes'] = ['roll_no'];
$transfer['transfers'][0]['on_hold'] = "1";
// $transfer['transfers'][0]['on_hold_until'] = "1671222870";
$paymentId = "Pay_heeu7333gg";

$api = new Api('API_KEY', 'API_SECRET');
$payment = $api->payment->fetch($paymentId)->transfer($transfer);
```

Comment: it gives me this error `The id provided does not exist`

Comment: Please check your payment Id and account id present in razor pay account.

Comment: I already checked and they are correct